# iOS 4 has an In-App SMS SDK for sending messages, but is there a way to have your App receive incoming SMS messages?

Tags: iphone, sms, ios4

iOS 4 has an In-App SMS SDK for sending messages, but is there a way to have your App receive incoming SMS messages?

Thanks so much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not on a non-jailbroken device.

Comment: thanks, Tom!  how about accessing the list of SMS messages that have already been received?  Do developers have access to that data the same way they have access to the users calendar events, music, contacts, etc.?

Comment: Afraid not, no. We're still pretty limited :(

Comment: for pretty good reason. Can you imagine the fallout if an app started storing people's texts.

Comment: I cannot imagine that, but I surely can imagine an App that uses the SMS protocol to receive notifications from a server, so that the user does not have to pay for internet fees.